# How to use RunProcess to run python interpreter

Tags: programming, external-calls

In a related question [How to use RunProcess to import external function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66022/how-to-use-runprocess-to-import-external-function)
@taliesin provides a very nice answer illustrating using RunProcess to launch a GO http server.

Has anyone, or does anyone know if it is possible, to use RunProcess[] to launch the python interpreter and run the interpreter using WriteLine and ReadLine as shown in the documentation for cmd on Windows?

If so then could you provide an example?