# Implementing Local HTTP Server

Tags: windows, java, webservices, socket

How might I implement a local HTTP server using either Java, C#, C or purely Mathematica?

It should be able to respond with Mathematica input to GET and POST requests ideally on W7.

This is related although [doesn't really work.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72551/reading-from-a-socket-stream)  If you would like you can read the license [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27785/implementing-a-100-mathematica-http-server)

Comment: A small-scale web server implemented using ProcessLink and Go can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66131/142).

Comment: @WReach thank you I'm trying to get it to run on Windows despite appearing to be written for OSX.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The following guide shows how to conduct communication between [nanohttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd), an http server for Java, and *Mathematica*. The result is a server that, if you go to its address in a web browser, displays the result of `SessionTime[]`, i.e. the time since the *Mathematica* kernel associated to the server started.

I'm going to write as if the reader was using OS X with Maven installed because that is the operating system I am using, but this solution works on all operating systems with the proper, obvious, modifications. Directories and so on. On OS X Maven can be installed with [Brew](http://brew.sh/) using

```
brew -install maven
```

Getting up and running with nanohttpd:

1. Download the latest version of nanohttpd from [Github](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/releases).
2. Follow the steps listed under "quickstart" on [nanohttpd.org](http://www.nanohttpd.org/)

Add this to the top of the sample app among the other imports:

```
import com.wolfram.jlink.*;
```

Locate JLink.jar on your harddrive. On OS X it is located at

```
/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links/JLink
```

Navigate to the app's directory and run the following command to include JLink.jar in the Maven project (with the appropriate modifications):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Links/JLink/JLink.jar -DgroupId=com.wolfram.jlink -DartifactId=JLink -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

And modify the app's pom.xml by adding the file as a dependency:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.wolfram.jlink</groupId>
      <artifactId>JLink</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

Check that you can still compile the application and that it still works. Now if that's true, replace the code in App.java with this (see the sample program [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/WritingJavaProgramsThatUseTheWolframLanguage.html)):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import com.wolfram.jlink.*;

import fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD;

public class App extends NanoHTTPD {

    KernelLink ml;

    public App() throws IOException {
        super(8888);
        start(NanoHTTPD.SOCKET_READ_TIMEOUT, false);

        try {
            String jLinkDir = "/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links/JLink";
            System.setProperty("com.wolfram.jlink.libdir", jLinkDir); // http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Aug/msg00664.html

            ml = MathLinkFactory.createKernelLink("-linkmode launch -linkname '\"/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel\" -mathlink'");

            // Get rid of the initial InputNamePacket the kernel will send
            // when it is launched.
            ml.discardAnswer();
        } catch (MathLinkException e) {
            throw new IOException("Fatal error opening link: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("\nRunning! Point your browers to http://localhost:8888/ \n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new App();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't start server:\n" + ioe);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {

        String msg = "<html><body><p>";

        try {
            ml.evaluate("SessionTime[]");
            ml.waitForAnswer();

            double result = ml.getDouble();

            msg = msg + Double.toString(result);
        } catch (MathLinkException e) {
            msg = msg + "MathLinkException occurred: " + e.getMessage();
        }
        msg = msg + "</p></body></html>";

        return newFixedLengthResponse(msg);
    }
}
```

Look up the line with `String jLinkDir =` and confirm that the directory is right. If you are using another operating system than OS X you also have to configure the line with `MathLinkFactory` in it. Information about that is available [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/WritingJavaProgramsThatUseTheWolframLanguage.html).

Compile the code and run it by (as you did before to run the sample app), navigating to the project's directory and executing the following commands:

```
mvcompile
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.stackexchange.mathematica.App"
```

where you have edited mainClass appropriately. You now have an HTTP server on the address http://localhost:8888/ that calls on a *Mathematica* kernel and uses its response to answer requests.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the response but being on Windows it is unlikely that I will accept this answer and give it the bounty.

Comment: @William It works on Windows but directories need to be changed. I don't have Windows so I can't try it, but if you try it on Windows then you can add a note detailing things that are specific to Windows. That would help people who come across this in the future.

Comment: The following link for nanohttpd https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/wiki/5-minute-Tutorial states the following `You'll need Linux or Mac OS....`.

Comment: @William Java works on Windows, and Maven works on Windows. I don't see why NanoHTTPD shouldn't work on Windows. The guide you quote is written for Unix, that's all I think.

Comment: Nothing would prevent you from writing the above code in JLink right?

Comment: @William The above code is written with JLink?

Comment: I was thinking it written like [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/CallingJavaFromTheWolframLanguage.html) so you could run the code inside mathematica and  not spawn a new kernel each time(although this could be avoided)

Answer (score 15):

The following is a sample implementation of a simple HTTP server in Wolfram Language code only:

https://github.com/arnoudbuzing/wolfram-server

You send it a POST request where the body data of the HTTP request contains the Wolfram Language code you wish to evaluate.

The (running) wolframserver.wls script processes the request by evaluating the code string and returning the result as [ExpressionJSON](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/ExpressionJSON.html) which should be generic enough to parse and process in most programming languages (including javascript for web browsers).

It's a new and evolving project for me, so please give it a star if this is useful to you because that will tell me how much interest there is in this (and how much time to spend on it for making improvements).

Answer (score 10):

Starting in Mathematica 12, there is a built-in function [`SocketListen`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SocketListen.html) that can start a web server and respond to HTTP requests.

`SocketListen` is also available in Mathematica 11.2, but only on an experimental basis.

Further reading: [Network Programming Guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NetworkProgramming.html).

Answer (score 4):

In 2023 new players joined our game

- [TCPServer](https://github.com/KirillBelovTest/TCPServer) - a general purpose tcp-server written using only WL
- [HTTPServer](https://github.com/KirillBelovTest/HTTPHandler) - an extension to TCPServer to manage GET/POST requests
- [WebSocketServer](https://github.com/KirillBelovTest/WebSocketHandler) - an extension to use Websockets protocol
- [CSockets](https://github.com/KirillBelovTest/CSockets) - a custom written in C high-performance asynchronous cross-platform sockets interface (as a replacement of buggy native `SocketListener`. Synthetic test shows `x67` of performance gain Server->Client)

Comment: Can the ``HTTPServer` use the `CSockets` to serve the GET/POST routes in place of the buggy `SocketListener` that has not seen any development for several years? It will be nice if you add  a dockerfile support to build this server and serve those REST end points. Looking forward to further development and docs to use it as mma based tiny prototyping back-ends.

Comment: Thanks, @PlatoManiac! I will ask a maintainer of those packages to reply ;)

Comment: @PlatoManiac of course! This is the main purpose of creating this package. A faster and more reliable interface for exchanging TCP packets. Now this package and other packages related to it are in the process of finalization, but you can write to me on the mail, which is specified on the github or contact me in any other way.

Comment: @PlatoManiac And yes docker file in todo list.

Answer (score 3):

Yes (and using pure Mathematica or WolframEngine)

https://jerryi.github.io/tinyweb-mathematica/