# How to lock a socket or create a queue for requests?

Tags: java, socket

I try to implement sockets from [java.net.ServerSocket](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) in Mathematica. I execute this code step by step:

```
Needs["JLink`"]
InstallJava[]

(* LinkObject[..] *)
```

After this I have to create server socket:

```
serverSocket = JavaNew["java.net.ServerSocket", 8080]
socket = serverSocket@accept[]

(* 
    << JavaObject[java.net.ServerSocket] >>
    << JavaObject[java.net.Socket] >> // after opening localhost:8080
*)
```

Now you need to open the page [http://localhost:8080](http:///localhost:8080). 
This page will be in a state of constant expectation, until an answer is sent.
So, now I can read data from the socket:

```
inputStream = socket@getInputStream[]
length = inputStream@available[]
(bytes = Table[inputStream@read[], {length - 1}]) // Short

(*
    << JavaObject[java.net.SocketInputStream] >>
    320
    {71, 69, 84, 32, 47, 32, 72, 84, 84, 80, 47, 49, 46, 49, 13, 10, 65, \
    <<286>>, 110, 58, 32, 75, 101, 101, 112, 45, 65, 108, 105, 118, 101, \
    13, 10, 13}
*)
```

But, if you refresh the page http://localhost:8080 during reading from the inputStream then get the exception. Reading the last of bytes after refresh the page:

```
inputStream@read[]

(* $Failed *)
```

> > During evaluation of In[..]:= Java::excptn: A Java exception occurred: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
> >         at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:154)
> >         at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
> >         at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:223).

The same will happen when you try to write to OutputStream after the page is updated. How can I lock a socket while reading a request and writing a response? How can I create a query queue, where the requests will come in at the time the socket is busy? Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111749/implementing-local-http-server