# Can one create a custom front-end for Mathematica?

Tags: front-end, interoperability, interface

I'd like to create my custom front-end for Mathematica. I know there's a console interface (launched as `math`), which mostly works great, but it can't really provide functionality of e.g. interactive (rotatable) `Plot3D` or `Manipulate`, although one can show 2D plots with `JavaGraphics` package.

Is there an official way of interacting with the kernel so as to be able to show the manipulator, 2D/3D plots etc. and provide the user feedback to the kernel, getting back updated results?

Comment: Yes.  The kernel communicates with the front end through MathLink. See chapter 2 of [the old MathLink tutorial](http://edenwaith.com/development/tutorials/mathlink/ML_Tut.pdf), as well as the MathLink (now WSTP) reference in the documentation.

Comment: If you want to use Java instead of C, J/Link comes with an simple example front end, see MathSessionPane http://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/Overview.html under "Some Special User Interface Classes".

Comment: @Szabolcs is it not an answer?

Comment: I felt that a proper answer should give more references, including a link to an example front end. I am sure that there is one out there. I thought [mash](http://ai.eecs.umich.edu/people/dreeves/mash/) worked like this, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Szabolcs I see the MathLink tutorial you linked to mentions `frontend.c` on MathSource.

Comment: It seems that file is very hard to find though...

Comment: Maybe here? http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/174/

Comment: Using [web*Mathematica*](http://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/) with a local server could be another option.

Comment: [This is a project](https://github.com/mmatera/iwolfram) that tries to make Mathematica available through a Jupyter notebook as a front-end. Based on [this comment](https://github.com/mmatera/iwolfram/issues/2#issuecomment-268037305), dynamic objects aren't supported currently, though.

Comment: I did not read your question carefully. Getting `Dynamic` stuff to work (including `Manipulate`) would require a lot of work, and implementing undocumented interfaces.  I do not think that it is a reasonable project to attempt.  Just showing text and graphics is another matter. That is entirely doable.

Comment: Also the Wolfram Cloud products can be viewed as JavaScript based front-ends that are rendered in your browser and connect to a Mathematica installation running on a server. From what I have seen, it looks like React is used for the dynamic things. In principle the same code could be used to create a desktop app.

Comment: Apropos what Karsten just said, [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111803/731) answer of mine shows how to set up an HTTP server in Java that could take input from the browser and forward it to Mathematica, in case you want to build the frontend in HTML/JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Now there are 2 ways AFAIK.

1. https://jerryi.github.io/wljs-docs/ amazing work.
2. A much more rudimentary solution, not a "front end", but meets your need.

> Is there an **official** way of **interacting** with the kernel so as to be able to show the **manipulator, 2D/3D plots** etc.

use wolfram player. And a simple vscode plugin.

```
Manipulate[
    Plot3D[x + y a,{x,0,5},{y,0,5}],{a,0,5}
]
```

[image]

https://github.com/asukaminato0721/mmaplayer

Which will almost 100% be like origin mathematica style.